# Error while accessing ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm accessing ABAddressBook using the following code:

```
+ (void)connectToAddressBook {
    if(!_addressBook)
    {
        CFErrorRef error;
        _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        NSLog(@"Address book %@", _addressBook);

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR WHILE ACCESSING ADDRESS BOOK: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
            CFRelease(error);
        }

        if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(_addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                _isAccessToContactsAllowed = granted;
            });
        }
        else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            _isAccessToContactsAllowed = YES;
        }
        else {
            _isAccessToContactsAllowed = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Address book opens fine, but for some reason error is not nil and logs the name of the current class:

```
ERROR WHILE ACCESSING ADDRESS BOOK: MyContactManager
```

Why is error not nil? Is my code somehow wrong? How can I detect and stop trying to access the address book in the case of a real error?

Comment: Check what the error says then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724995/my-contact-not-add-in-addressbook-in-ios-7

Comment: @Ilesh - thanks, *error works. It's strange though. That's how it was in the beginning but it broke a lot so I had to rewrite it (there was an error and the debugger got stuck while trying to log it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my fixed method thanks to feedback from Ilesh:

```
+ (void)connectToAddressBook {
    if(!_addressBook) {
        CFErrorRef *error = nil;
        _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

        // To test if error is not nil:
        //error = CFErrorCreate(NULL, CFSTR("Hello, world."), 111, NULL);

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR WHILE ACCESSING ADDRESS BOOK: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
            CFRelease(error);
        }
        else {
            if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(_addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                    _isAccessToContactsAllowed = granted;
                });
            }
            else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                _isAccessToContactsAllowed = YES;
            }
            else {
                _isAccessToContactsAllowed = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

It appears that my initial mistake was not assigning error to *nil*. Address book creation doesn't set error **unless there actually is an error**. So my unassigned variable pointed to some random place in memory and that's why I had random errors at my first try.

What's more, ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions will return *nil* if there is an error, so the correct way to do this is:

```
if(_addressBook) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // there is an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your whole code to this

```
+ (void)connectToAddressBook {
    if(!_addressBook)
    {
_addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook,
                                                 ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                                                     if (granted)
                                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        _isAccessToContactsAllowed = granted; 
                                                     });

                                                         });


    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
_isAccessToContactsAllowed = YES;

    });
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Nil message:@"You don't have permission of access contacts for access go to Setting-" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know if there is an error when trying to create the address book.